# How to use localstorage to store all checkbox boolean values in a list to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The code looks like this:

```
<div id="list">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="3">
</div>
```

In another html pane (a separate template), I want to store all those checkbox (`checked`/`unchecked`) booleans into an array. What I did looks like:

```
var array = [];
var checkboxli = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxli.length; i++)
{
  array.push($("#input.prop('checked')"));
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I have other templates using tag name "`input`", so I need to limit the tag name to the ones under `"#list"` id (some sort of css selector perhaps). Currently, both `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` and `$("#input.prop('checked')")` won't work. There might be other syntax problems. Please help me resolve. Thanks.

EDIT: It seems like I didn't communicate my intention well. Here is what I want to get out of the list:
An array that looks like

```
[true, false, true, true, true...]
```

in which each boolean value represents whether the corresponding input checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are already using jquery, you can go like this:

Assuming this HTML

```
<div id="list">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" id="2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" checked="checked">
</div>
```

And this script:

```
var array = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']","#list").each(function(){
     array.push($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

You would get something like this:

```
array = [ true, false, true ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var checkboxli = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

you can use:

```
var checkboxli = document.querySelectorAll("#list>input[type=checkbox]"); //array of checkboxes
```

now you have all of the checkboxes under the list element.

if you want only the checked checkboxes you can use:

```
var checkboxli = document.querySelectorAll("#list>input[type=checkbox][checked]");
```

Comment: I like the conciseness of your solution. However, when I try alert(checkboxli), the popup says "[object NodeList]" instead of displaying each element... Any idea why? At the end, I would like to use localstorage to put that into JSON string.. and load it later

Comment: I re-read my question, I think I digressed a bit on my intention. My intention is to create an boolean type array that stores the true/false (corresponds to checked/unchecked) values of all input elements... Can that be done?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (which is Array-like, that means you can iterate over it), that's why alert will print the object type ([object NodeList])

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It retrieves all `IDs` from all `checked` `check-boxes`, stores in an `array` and then stores in `local-storage` as an `string`:

```
var itemsChecked = [] ;
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index, item){
   itemsChecked.push($(item).attr('id'));
})

localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(itemsChecked));
```

Later, to retrieved data from localstorage, use the following:

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems')); 
// returns array of IDs
```

Comment: I think this is a better way to store the data then what the OP came up with BUT this is not what he asked for.

Answer (score -1):

A more suitable approach would be to capture the XPath of each element starting from the body. You could use a [getPath](http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-getpath/) jQuery plugin, Thus you won't be dependent upon a specific string like the List.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    getPath: function( path ) {
       // The first time this function is called, path won't be defined.
       if ( typeof path == 'undefined' ) path = '';

       // If this element is <html> we've reached the end of the path.
       if ( this.is('html') )
           return 'html' + path;

       // Add the element name.
       var cur = this.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();

       // Determine the IDs and path.
       var id = this.attr('id'),
           class = this.attr('class');

       // Add the #id if there is one.
       if ( typeof id != 'undefined' )
          cur += '#' + id;

       // Add any classes.
       if ( typeof class != 'undefined' )
          cur += '.' + class.split(/[\s\n]+/).join('.');

       // Recurse up the DOM.
       return this.parent().getPath( ' > ' + cur + path );
   }
});
```

Comment: way to complicated for a simple thing like this!

Comment: You don't have to be negative. Its a robust and legit solution and I use it all the time. Your simple solution might be a problem in a month or so when someone will change the HTML. Its your choice whether to use it or not, you don't have to mark it as not useful because it is!